# Symfony2.1: how to render a "repeated" widget by hand

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, symfony-2.1

In **Symfony2.1** (as well in Symfony2.0) one can [render a widget by hand in a Twig template](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-each-field-by-hand). So, if one would to render a text field name "username", the related *label*, *error* and *input* can be rendered separately, i.e.:

```
{{ form_label(form.username) }}
{{ form_errors(form.username) }}
{{ form_widget(form.username) }}
```

In Symfony2.1, the `Repeated` field group has been introduced. It is useful to ensure the user is not inserting a wrong value for an important entry (e.g. the *email* or *password*).

The question is, **how to render it in a Twig template by hand**?

Please, notice that `{{ form_widget(form.username) }}` in this case will render the whole component (i.e. both *labels* and *inputs*).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    $builder->add('userPass', 'repeated', array(
        'type'     => 'password',
        'label'    => 'Zayso Password',
        'required' => true,
        'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
        'constraints' => new NotBlank(),

        'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Zayso Password'),
        'second_options' => array('label' => 'Zayso Password(repeat)'),

        'first_name'  => 'pass1', // form.userPass.pass1
        'second_name' => 'pass2', // form.userPass.pass2
    ));
```

In your template you can do: {{ form_widget(form.userPass.pass1 }}.  Not sure where it is documented but found it somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Late answer, but you can also add

> {{ form_widget(form.username.first) }}

to generate the first widget element.

If you want to display the `label` and `widget` separately, you can use:

```
{{ form_label(form.username.first) }}
{{ form_errors(form.username.first) }}
{{ form_widget(form.username.first) }}

{{ form_label(form.username.second) }}
{{ form_errors(form.username.second) }}
{{ form_widget(form.username.second) }}
```

Here is the documentation for [Repeated Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/repeated.html).